# Angular radio button Label does 't show correct

Tags: angular, typescript, radio-button, formgroups

This is my component code. In here radio button label doesn't show correctly when I am going to edit it. Radio button value does n't correctly set to the form value. It always show as No. Now I have added `[ngModel]` & `[value]`. But still i can't see the variable correctly.

```
 Form: FormGroup;
 ngOnInit(): void {
   this.createForm();
  if (this.isEdit) {  
  this.editForms();
   }
 }

 private createForm() {
    this.Form = this.formBuilder.group({     
      isRepository: [{ value: '', disabled: false }],
      remember: true
    });

isPrivateCheck(val: boolean) {
    this.isPrivate = val;
    if (this.isPrivate) {
      this.buttonName = 'Yes';
    } else {
      this.buttonName = 'No';
    } 
  }
```

This is my html code

```
<form [formGroup]="Form">
    <div class="form-group">
            <label>Private Repository</label>
            <div class="switch">

                <input (change)="isPrivateCheck(false)" type="radio" class="switch-input" id="yes" [ngModel]="isRepository"  [value]="buttonName" name="isRepository" formControlName="isRepository">
             <label  for="yes" class="switch-label switch-label-off">No</label>
                <input (change)="isPrivateCheck(true)" type="radio" class="switch-input" id="no" [ngModel]="isRepository" [value]="buttonName" name="isRepository>
            <label for="no" class="switch-label switch-label-on">Yes</label>
<span class="switch-selection"></span>
            </div>
        </div>

</form>
```

when i remove the html code

```
<label for="no" class="switch-label switch-label-on">Yes</label>
```

I can't see any label value at all.

Answer (score 0):

I found some syntax errors in your code. I don't know if is it really happened? or is it simply a sample to publish in StackOverflow. Like - Your does not close your second input field. Duplicate name with 'isPrivate'.
I fix some of your code. And it works.

component.ts

```
Form: FormGroup;
isPrivate = false;
buttonName;
constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
this.createForm();
}

 private createForm() {
   this.Form = this.formBuilder.group({
   isRepository: [{ value: '', disabled: false }],
   remember: true
});
}

checkIsPrivate(val: boolean) {
  this.isPrivate = val;
  if (this.isPrivate) {
   this.buttonName = 'Yes';
  } else {
   this.buttonName = 'No';
  }
}
```

component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="Form">
<div class="form-group">
<label>Private Repository</label>
<div class="switch">

  <input (change)="checkIsPrivate(false)" type="radio" class="switch-input" id="yes" [value]="buttonName" name="isRepository" formControlName="isRepository"/>
  <label  for="yes" class="switch-label switch-label-off">No</label>
  <input (change)="checkIsPrivate(true)" type="radio" class="switch-input" id="no" [value]="buttonName" name="isRepository"/>
  <label for="no" class="switch-label switch-label-on">Yes</label>
  <span class="switch-selection"></span>
  <div>{{buttonName}}</div>
  </div>
 </div>
    </form>
```

I make a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-iumbqb?file=src/app/app.component.html) sample based on your code. You can check if it solves your problem.

Comment: Actually no , there 's no that kind of an issue. My issue is radio button always shows this `<label for="no" class="switch-label switch-label-on">Yes</label>` values.

Comment: Instead of this what do you want?

Comment: I want to display correct label set for this radio button when i am going to edit this form

Comment: For edit, I add the default value as "Yes". Then change some code. Will you visit stackblitz link again and check if it works as your requirement?